# global variable won't change in other thread in c

Tags: c, linux, global-variables

I have a global variable in c program, and my environment is Linux.
When I change my global var in main thread, I see the change is right but nothing happen in other thread.
My global is declared in .h file and the .c is the same file name.
But if I change the global in one other thread, and the other threads will change.
I have print the memory of the global var, and it's the same in main and other threads.
Below is my code sample.

```
int pause_flag;

    int initThread() {
    int err;

    err = pthread_create(&user_request_thread, NULL, (void *)&user_request_handler, NULL);
    if (err != 0)
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);

    printLog("Agent-Less service", "start...");

    closelog();
    pthread_join(user_request_thread, NULL);    
    pthread_detach(user_request_thread);

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

    int pause() { 
    setPauseFlag(1);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

    void user_request_handler(void *arg) {
    while (1) {
        printf("pause_flag %d\n", getPauseFlag());
        sleep(5);
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}
void setPauseFlag(int value) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&pause_lock);
    pause_flag = value;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pause_lock);
}

int getPauseFlag() {
    int temp;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&pause_lock);
    temp = pause_flag;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pause_lock);

    return temp;;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

On multi-core systems, even `volatile` is not enough to guarantee synchronization between threads.  `volatile` will force a write to the underlying hardware, which could be a hardware register in some peripheral chip, or just a location in DRAM. But it won't necessarily update the variable on a different processor core, if that other core has a cached copy of the variable.  In other words, `volatile` doesn't force cache coherency across multiple processor cores.

To force an update to a variable that is guaranteed visible in all threads on all cores, you need to use one of the kernel's synchronization mechanisms, e.g. a semaphore.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier

See also the link provided by pat in the comments.

The code for the `get` function should look like this

```
int getPauseFlag()
{
    int temp;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&pause_lock);
    temp = pause_flag;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pause_lock);

    return temp;
}
```

Comment: See [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_11) for a list of memory barrier APIs

Comment: aren't those threads in the same process? So that they will shared the same global variable.

Comment: @sowrdking I've added a link to a wikipedia article for your consideration.

Comment: @user3386109 I add mutex lock, but the result is not changing.

Comment: @sowrdking The mutex lock must be used everywhere that `pause_flag` is accessed, e.g. in `user_request_handler`

Comment: @user3386109 I add two function for set/get, and I put mutex lock in there. The result is "not" good!! The setPauseFlag only called in main thread.

Comment: I use command line to call the pause function, will this affect the result?

Comment: @sowrdking In response to your first comment, I have added some code to my answer.  In response to your second comment, "How, exactly, are you calling the `pause` function from the command line?"

Comment: @user3386109 I'm running a service in Linux, so I use command line to start service. My service can parse the parameter I gave to decide which function to call. So, when I start the service, I use pause command to call the setPauseFlag. By the way, after I change the get function, it still won't change.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49917/discussion-between-user3386109-and-sowrdking)